# How do I get my script to submit two forms in series?

Tags: javascript, ajax, greasemonkey

I have two pages with one form at each. When you submit the first form, you will move to the 2nd page with the second form.
How do I submit both forms in one Greasemonkey script.

Step by step:

1. Open Page_1
2. Click submit_button
3. Submit action moved us to Page_2
4. Click submit_button_2

Note that both pages have the same URL, but Page_1 shows on 'GET', Page_2 on 'POST'.  (Editor's note: They may be AJAX-powered forms or submit-to-same-page forms.)

Comment: Added:
I haven't access to server pages. All pages are *.php

Comment: What do you mean by "in one JS script"? Just include the external file in both pages.

Comment: I have greasemonkey script what I want to change. It works on every page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add both urls to @include list and follow this pseudo-code:

```
if (isUrl1) {
    submitFormAtUrl1;
} else {
    submitFormAtUrl2;
}
```

Example:

```
// @include http://domain/page1.php
// @include http://domain/page2.php

...

if ("/page1.php" == location.pathname) {
    form1.submit();
} else {
    form2.submit();
}
```

Comment: Pages have same URl, but Page_1 shows on 'GET', Page_2 on 'POST'

Answer (score 1):

If you *always* want those forms clicked, use a script like the following.  This approach also works on AJAXified forms/pages, like yours:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     _Submit either of 2 forms
// @include  {{{Page_1}}}
// @include  {{{Page_2}}}
// @require  http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js
// @require  https://gist.github.com/raw/2625891/waitForKeyElements.js
// @grant    GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==
/*- The @grant directive is needed to work around a major design change
    introduced in GM 1.0.
    It restores the sandbox.
*/

waitForKeyElements ("SUBMIT_BUTTON_1 CSS SELECTOR", clickOnSubmitButton);
waitForKeyElements ("SUBMIT_BUTTON_2 CSS SELECTOR", clickOnSubmitButton);

function clickOnSubmitButton (jNode) {
    var clickEvent  = document.createEvent ('MouseEvents');
    clickEvent.initEvent ('click', true, true);
    jNode[0].dispatchEvent (clickEvent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Some example code would help but the easiest way to submit both forms at once is going to be combining them into one page. If you want the two forms to be broken up visually, you could use jQuery to keep the 2nd section of the form hidden until the user clicks a button, then hide the first section and show the second.

Another option would be to submit the first form, then add all of its responses to hidden form elements server-side on the second page.

Comment: "Another option would be to submit the first form, then add all of its responses to hidden form elements server-side on the second page." -- that was going to my suggestion.